# IntelliJ: find code path between two methods

Tags: intellij-idea

I have two methods in my code base. I would like to figure out, if there exists a path in which one will be called from the other. Is there some way to achieve this easily in IntelliJ without digging manually through call hierarchies?

Comment: Would it help to run a unit test with code coverage, and see if the second method turns green?

Comment: No, the code has hundreds of possible code paths. Right now I am only trying to determine if a method could be called, not whether it definitely is called in some scenario.

Comment: Well if you reach 100% code coverage then you have in fact established that ;)

Answer (score 26):

The following might work for you on *IntellIJ IDEA 16* and higher. It uses call hierarchies, but automates the digging;-)

- invoke `Call Hierarchy` <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+H</kbd> on method 1.
- click on the `Callee Methods Hierarchy` button in the tool window that appears to show all methods that are called by method 1.
- click on the `Expand All` button a couple of times to show called methods until the desired depth.
- Invoke `Find Usages` on method 2 and select the Scope `Hierarchy 'Callees of 1'`

Result: all calls of method 2 in method 1's call hierarchy.

Comment: Genius! Can get really slow with wide hierarchies, and it's hard to see the actual path, but still great! Much faster than searching manually, that's for sure.

Comment: I cannot find a way to select the `Hierarchy 'Callees of 1'` scope in `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3`. Does that capability still exist?

Comment: The Hierarchy scope has indeed disappeared. It's a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206342).

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers the ticket now says fixed? yet I still can't find this option in 2019.2

Comment: It works for me in 2019.2. Make sure you have a hierarchy tool window open, or the scope won't appear.

Comment: Ah, I've found it now. Still it only seems to work for visible nodes only, and unfortunately I have a bunch of recursive calls in my code base and so the expand all just goes on forever.

Comment: The [recursive calls issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131162) should now be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers can you post a screenshot? I am using IDEA 2019.2.4 and can't find the button

Comment: I'm on 2020.3.2 and the Scope selection button does not seem to appear in the Find Usages window. :/

Comment: I've filed [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-279315) for this.

Answer (score 4):

I've done the following:

- Select method 2 and invoke call hierarchy with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
- Click `Expand All` on the hierarchy panel
- Click inside the hierarchy panel, and start typing the name of method 1